# GETjson 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm trying to render a list of all my users using Angular, but I'm getting a 500 internal server error when I try to load `users.json`.

This is my service,
    angular.module('users')

```
  .factory('UsersFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
      loadUsers: function() {
        return $http.get('/users.json');
      }
    };
  }])
```

And this is the controller,
    angular.module('users', [])

```
  .controller('UserListCtrl', [

    '$scope', 'UsersFactory',
    function ($scope, UsersFactory) {

      var init = function(){
        UsersFactory.loadUsers().then(function(response) {
          $scope.users = response.data;
          console.log ($scope.users)
        });
      }
      init();

    }
  ]);
```

And the template where I try to render the users,

```
Users
.user_container{"ng-repeat" => "user in user"}
  {{ user.name }}
```

And this is the error output in my rails server,

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 27ms (ActiveRecord: 22.9ms)

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template users/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/alucardu/sites/movieseat/app/views"
  * "/home/alucardu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.5.2/app/views"
):
```

Comment: the error is related to your server side code and with angular code, so it would be better that you put the server-side code and remove js code from the question

Comment: @entre thanks for the input. Makes sence. Can you help me with setting up the controller and the routes to resolve this?

Comment: sorry but i have no knowledge about ror so cant help

Answer (score 0):

By putting this,

```
@users = User.all
  respond_with(@users)
```

In my user_controller.rb and this

```
resources :users, only: [:index, :show]
```

In my routes.rb I got it to work.